# Contour lines on incomplete seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have succeeded in making contour lines on a seaborn heatmap using the `LineCollection` answer of the link below:

[Contour (iso-z) or threshold lines in seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011748/contour-iso-z-or-threshold-lines-in-seaborn-heatmap)

However, the dataset I have is not completely filled. It basically has 2 borders. because of this, for each iso line add, I get 3. one is at the correct location, the other two are at the top and bottom borders of the heatmap.
The problem can be reproduced by adding a column filled with zeros:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
flights["1965"] = 0
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt='d')


def add_iso_line(ax, value, color):
    v = flights.gt(value).diff(axis=1).fillna(False).to_numpy()
    h = flights.gt(value).diff(axis=0).fillna(False).to_numpy()

    try:
        l = np.argwhere(v.T)
        vlines = np.array(list(zip(l, np.stack((l[:, 0], l[:, 1] + 1)).T)))

        l = np.argwhere(h.T)
        hlines = np.array(list(zip(l, np.stack((l[:, 0] + 1, l[:, 1])).T)))

        lines = np.vstack((vlines, hlines))
        ax.add_collection(LineCollection(lines, lw=3, colors=color))
    except:
        pass


add_iso_line(ax, 200, 'b')
add_iso_line(ax, 400, 'y')
```

Is there a way to adjust the code, such that it only plots the correct iso line?

Comment: Maybe you can replace the zero-values in your data with `np.nan`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try this on the example it throws an error:
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'

Comment: So, you might want to change `fmt='d')` by '.0f' or so.