# How to draw outer edge of meshes above threshold with python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D pseudocolor plot that I create with pcolor of matplotlib.
I would like to highlight the outer edges of the meshes that have value above a threshold, like in the image.
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vilwk.jpg)

I have managed to draw all the edges of the meshes by creating rectangles and using add_patch.
[This is what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cVTI.png)

But I think I need to first join all the rectangles into one shape and then plot the outer edge. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

z = np.array([[0,0,0,1,1],[1,0,6,1,3],[1,7,10,1,2],[1,1,0,0,2],[0,0,2,1,2]])
threshold = 5

fig = plt.figure(figsize =(12, 10))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
c = ax.pcolor(z, cmap = 'viridis')
for i in range(z.shape[0]): 
    for j in range(z.shape[1]): 
        if z[i, j] > threshold:
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((j, i), 1, 1, fc='none', ec='crimson', lw=5))
ax.axis('off')  
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you ok to use opencv or does it have to work only with np ?

Comment: See also [Contour (iso-z) or threshold lines in seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hack (without need to use any extra libraries) may be to create 2 layers of patches.

1. The lower-level patches need to be a bit wider and have the color that is needed for the border.
2. The upper-level patches are basically repeating of the underlying plot values and obscure the lower patches everywhere except the widenings.

Please see this code as an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

z = np.array([[0,0,0,1,1],[1,0,6,1,3],[1,7,10,1,2],[1,1,0,0,2],[0,0,2,1,2]])
threshold = 5

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6, 5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
c = ax.pcolor(z, cmap=cmap)

for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    for j in range(z.shape[1]):
        if z[i, j] > threshold:
            print(f'i = {i}, j = {j}, z = {z[i,j]}')
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((j-0.06, i-0.06), 1.12, 1.12, fc='crimson', lw=0))

for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    for j in range(z.shape[1]):
        if z[i, j] > threshold:
            rel_value = (z[i, j] - np.min(z)) / (np.max(z) - np.min(z))
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((j, i), 1, 1, fc=cmap(rel_value), lw=0))

ax.axis('off')  
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)
ax.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: This is what the result can look like]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `shapely`. Probably not the most efficient one but the idea is quite straightforward: create a rectangle per pixel above the threshold, merge them, and display the resulting polygons.

```py
# [...]

from matplotlib.patches import Polygon as mplPolygon
from shapely.geometry import Polygon as shPolygon
from shapely.ops import unary_union

# [...]
c = ax.pcolor(z, cmap = 'viridis')

# Get pixel position above the threshold
Y, X = np.where(z > threshold)
positions = np.dstack((X, Y))[0]

# Create a rectangle per position and merge them.
rectangles = [shPolygon([xy, xy + [1, 0], xy + [1, 1], xy + [0, 1]]) for xy in positions]
polygons = unary_union(rectangles)

# Shapely will return either a Polygon or a MultiPolygon. 
# Make sure the structure is the same in any case.
if polygons.geom_type == "Polygon":
    polygons = [polygons]
else:
    polygons = polygons.geoms

# Add the matplotlib Polygon patches
for polygon in polygons:
    ax.add_patch(mplPolygon(polygon.exterior.coords, fc='none', ec='crimson', lw=5))

# [...]
```

Here are few result examples:
[image]